# How can I pass a javascript file with an object into a react Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have a file with a javascript object and I want to pass it to my main App.js and then send it though a Test component that I have. I've tried a couple of different ways But I cant seem to get it to work properly. I either get an error or an undefined. The only way i've gotten it to work was if i disregarded the data.js file and put that code inside of my App.js underneath the render function, but I know there is a better way to do it, I just dont know how.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Test from './Components/Test'
import data from './data'
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
render() {

return (
   <div className="App">

    <Test data={data}/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Test.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Test extends Component {
render(props) {
console.log(props)
return (
  <div>

    <h3>{props.data}</h3>
  </div>
  );
}
}

export default Test;
```

data.js:

```
  export const data = {
  "id": 173,
  "deviceId": "1011000000000002",
  "imei": "352588070009004",
  "smsGate": "16466652134",
  "registerDate": "2018-03-12 22:14:21",
  "activationDate": "2018-03-12T22:26:52.439Z",
  "number": "15202459297",
  "wakeUpCyclesLeft": -27,
  "lastWakeUpTime": "2018-03-22T20:27:52.565Z",
  "nextWakeUpTime": "2018-03-22T20:30:00.000Z",
  "customerName": "ABCD",
  "isActive": true,
  "responseTimeout": 60,
  "location": [
 {
 "time": "2018-03-21T17:00:39.000Z",
  "point": {
  "lng": -115.13,
   "lat": 36.1132
 },
 "address": null,
"thirdPartyPoint": {
 "lng": -115.13,
"lat": 36.1132
 },
"localPoint": null,
"gpsPoint": null
}

],
"soil_sensor": 20,
"tip_sensor": false,
"water_level": 74
}

export default data;
```

Comment: try  removing `export` from `export const`. You have a default export statement at bottom

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I did not see that there is a default export. Then, it must work, it is just exporting it again is unnecessary. Just use one exporting method. One last thing, do not render an object as a React child directly.

---

Try importing data like that:

`import { data } from './data'`;

If you omit curly braces that means you are importing a default export from data file named `data`. But, you don't have a default export so you must use curly braces.

Comment: there is a default export

Comment: Oh, I did not see that. Thanks @charlietfl, I edited my answer (as it does not answer anything now :) ).

Comment: so in my Test.js I put `this.props.data.id` and it comes up like i thought it should. Is there are shorter way? Or should I just use destructuring?

Comment: Shorter way for what? A whole object itself is useless for your front-end. You need to extract the related data and render it or use somewhere else I think.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can do something like this:

```
export const data = {
  ...
}
export default data;
```

I would try one way or another:

```
export default { ... };
```

or

```
export const data = { ... }
```

Another thing, you use `props` which should be passed as an argument to `render`, isn't it `preact` thing? Also, React will throw a warning if you try to render Object. Change render to something like:

```
<div>
   <h3>{this.props.data.customerName}</h3>
</div>
```